Recursive search and replace a string with dot in text files on Mac
Team, I see there are multiple similar questions but I did try some answers and still not able to get what I want. I want to replace a text as "product-ui-test-creds.json" to "vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json" from all files in directory and sub dirs
sample grep
Command> grep product-ui-test-creds.json * -r
ci/product/verify-ui/e2e.jenkinsfile:        product_Test_User = credentials('product-ui-test-creds.json')
deployments/product-ui/e2e/e2e.jenkinsfile:    product_Test_User = credentials('product-ui-test-creds.json')
deployments/product-stuff/ui-ci/Jenkinsfile:    CREDS = credentials('product-ui-test-creds.json')

expected output
Command> grep vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json * -r
ci/product/verify-ui/e2e.jenkinsfile:        product_Test_User = credentials('vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json')
deployments/product-ui/e2e/e2e.jenkinsfile:    product_Test_User = credentials('vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json')
deployments/product-stuff/ui-ci/Jenkinsfile:    CREDS = credentials('vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json')

I tried this
 LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/product-ui-test-creds.json/vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json/g {} +

or
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' s/this/that/g {} +

does not give any output and neither it changes anything in files.

You should escape the . in the regexp, although in this case I don't thjink it should make any difference.

Change -name '*.txt' to -name '*.jenkinsfile'

LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '*.jenkinsfile' -exec sed -i '.orig' "s/'\(product-ui-test-creds\.json'\)/'vaulted-\1/g" {} +

@RenaudPacalet I added them to limit the match, so one can't end up with things like vaulted-vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json

@jhnc Oh, I see, and I also just realized that they are also in the OP's input. Sorry, you're right, please ignore my comment.

What is the strange -r doing at the end of your grep command? Do you really have a file of this name?

user1934428: -r, --recursive like --directories=recurse same as if you put it ahead of the file arguments.

suggesting to try:
sed -i 's/product-ui-test-creds.json/vaulted-product-ui-test-creds.json/g' $(find -type f)

